# Why would "an mule" be used instead of "a mule"?

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, articles, indefinite-articles, sandhi

As generally agreed and as extensively discussed in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an), "an" should be used in place of the more common "a" where the following word begins with a vowel sound.

I have just encountered for the first time an instance of the phrasing

> an mule

in the book [*Why Chemical Reactions Happen*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qUucAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&dq=%22useful+analogy+here+is+that+of+an+mule%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5o-bv2sTkAhXJs54KHdtjC7gQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22an%20mule%22&f=false) (James Keeler and Peter Wothers, Oxford University Press, 2003). (This book is not mine. I was sitting opposite a friend when the friend mentioned the unusual phrasing.)

This phrasing appears to contradict the rule discussed above, since "mule" is, as far as I am aware, pronounced /mjuːl/ (see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mule#Pronunciation)).

Here is the context. The author is using an analogy to explain a chemistry concept (the italics are not mine, but the bold emphasis is):

> A useful analogy here is that of **an *mule***, which we get by crossing a horse with a donkey. To describe **an mule** as a horse or a donkey would be inaccurate and it certainly does not interconvert rapidly between the two! Rather we need to recognize that although **an mule** has parts that are reminiscent of a horse and parts that a reminiscent of a donkey, it is something altogether different.

Looking for other examples online, I have managed to find one on Wikipedia's [*List of Siege engines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Siege_engines). Discussing a Siege engine, the Scorpio:

> Similar to the ballista, but smaller. Was sometimes mounted on **an mule-drawn cart**.

Other examples are difficult to find, but here's one from a user-posted question on Answers.com (referring, notably, to a kind of deer rather than the animal, a mule):

> **Is an mule deer an omnivore?**
>
> No. Mule deer are herbivores. ...

What is going on? Is there an irregular pronunication of "mule" of which I am not aware? Is this some strange language quirk, some archaic spelling that I am encountering for the first time?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98525/discussion-on-question-by-c-ren-why-would-an-mule-be-used-instead-of-a-mule).

Comment: The perils of "Global" replace.

Comment: Voting to close the Q as a NARQ.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been marked as off-topic. I think that this question concerns Word Choice and/or Grammar, and therefore is a fit for this site as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The original printing had "an ass" instead of "an mule". That error was not lost on the chemistry community. See, for instance, [Krenos's 2004 review](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed081p201) of the text in the *Journal of Chemical Education*:

> In Chapter 10, bonding in extended conjugated systems and resonance are introduced with the horse + donkey = ass analogy (it is likely the hybrid animal *mule* is intended instead of *ass*, however).

It seems the editors subsequently made an <del>error</del> mistake.

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct for providing strong evidence for the source of the typo.

Comment: +1 for the "an mistake" :)

Comment: Reminds me of the urban legend about an author who, at the last minute, decided to change a character's name from _David_ to _Jeff_. After it had gone to print, and much too late, he remembered that there was a scene that took place in the Victoria and Albert Museum involving the replica statue, _Michelangelo's Jeff_.

Comment: This has also happened in the opposite direction: *an umpire* was originally *a noumper* (non-peer) and *a newt* was once *an ewt* or *an eft*.

Comment: Perfect explanation. :)

Comment: "Juncture loss, she turned me into a newt!"

Answer (score 89):

It's just a typo, and it probably originally said "an ass". That would have been changed because it's incorrect (an ass is a donkey, not a horse–donkey cross) and, even if it were correct, the fact that ass means well, you know, *ass*, might be distracting enough to make it worth changing.

Another source of this kind of typo is when an adjective has been added or removed and the article hasn't been updated (e.g., "an elephant" becoming "an big elephant" or "an amazing coincidence" becoming "an coincidence"). That's presumably not happened in this particular text, since there are several instances of "an mule".

Comment: Isn't this just a recapitulation of @FumbleFingers statement above?

Comment: @DavidM Apparently, yes. If they'd posted it as an answer, I'd have seen it; this is part of the reason why we don't post answers in comments...

Comment: Actually, *ass* is rather different from *arse.*

Comment: "since there are several instances of "an mule" ... or somebody used *find all and replace*.

Comment: What about the mule deer example?  Just a typo on it's own?  I can't imagine an ass deer is a thing (and I'll admit, I'm afraid to Google it).

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife I assume so, yes.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: In traditional British English, sure, they’re different: the farm animal is an *ass*, your buttocks are an *arse* — they’re spelled differently, and for many speakers they’re pronounced differently too (depending on accent).  But in American English, both the buttocks and the animal are an *ass*, and are pronounced identically — perfect homonyms.  (And using *ass* for the buttocks is now becoming more common in British English too, both in spelling and pronunciation.)

Comment: The cart-pulling beast could have been an *ass* (or even an *ox*) before switching to *mule* - realistically any available beast of burden would have been used. The citation appears to be to a source in Latin so translation would be required.

Comment: @Adam Chris is referring to the quote in the question about "an mule-drawn cart", which doesn't make any reference to the animal in question being a hybrid.

Comment: @DavidRicherby good point.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - hybrid vehicles are old news; we should be going full electric now.....  oh... wait... wrong site!  :-D :-D

Comment: @PLL as a Brit, I've been caught out by using *ass* in the equine sense, and having my text being rejected by a US-centric profanity checker.

Comment: @Spudley Good thing you weren't riding your ass from Scunthorpe to Penistone, or the profanity checker would have exploded.