# Is it "a SW" or "an SW"?

Tags: abbreviations, indefinite-articles

First of all: I am aware of the rule for "**a**" vs. "**an**" be it a noun or an abbreviation following (see [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)). So following this rule the answer would be "**an SW**".

But how about:

> I need to perform __ SW update.

Will the rule still be valid if you consider that - in the context of SW=software - probably no one will ever read this as "*an ess-double-ju update*" but always read this as "*a software update*"?

What would you recommend here?

Comment: You misunderstood the rule. The rule is: use "a" if it's pronounced starting with a consonant and "an" if it's pronounced starting with a vowel. If "SW" is pronounced *software*, then it starts with a consonant sound, and you use "a".

Comment: You can't account for everyone, so only worry about how you're reading it. Once you know that, you can pick your article.

Comment: This is author's choice.  How is the reader likely to pronounce the term?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was thinking so: author's choice + expected pronounciation (instead of how it's written)